# Does Boost provide a facility for printing uBLAS datatypes?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-ublas

I'm debugging an application that massively uses uBLAS vectors and matrices. I would like to print them to console with something like:

```
boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double> v;
// ...filling v...
std::cout << v; // or boost::whatever << v;
```

Exact output format does dot matter, I just want to look at the vector contents. Does Boost provide such an overload of `operator<<` for `std::ostream` with uBLAS types? Any other short way of printing uBLAS types would be OK too. It's not a big effort to write these functions by myself, but I'm looking for a "standard" technique to do it, if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp` defines `operator<<` for uBlas components.